# How can I grep to filter results from ls?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, grep

I have a problem with a grep command.
I have 3 tasks:

a) find and show only dir's for "ls -l"

```
ls -l | grep ^d   # which works good
```

b) only files which names starts with a digit

```
ls | grep ^[0-9]
```

works too but for files and dirs,it have to work only for files, how can I do that?

c) files that have a "x" right for groups

```
ls -l | grep "^-*x" # it shows every file
```

How I can make these commands for b) and c) works?

Comment: Parsing `ls` is a bad idea for this. Use `find` command.

Comment: ...see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) on the Wooledge wiki, and [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) find and show only dir's for "ls -l"

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec ls -l {} \;
```

b) only files which names starts with a digit

```
find . -maxdepth 1  -type f -name "[0-9]*"
```

c) files that have a "x" right for groups

```
find  . -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm /g+x
```

Comment: Heh. I only answered this myself because I was worried there would be other answers which tried to take the literalist approach. Apparently I needn't have worried. That said, as currently implemented with `-regex`, (b) is needlessly incompatible (requiring GNU extensions to `find`), and will match any file if it's in a directory that starts with a digit.

Comment: If you add the `-ls` action, you'll get the same output as `ls -l`.

Comment: I meant the actual `-ls` action: `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -ls` (but it's not specified by POSIX, as far as I can see).

Comment: BTW, `-exec ... {} +` has been POSIX-specified since 2006 (IIRC, and was available well before that), making that a more efficient alternative to `-exec ... {} \;` for commands (like `ls`) where multiple files to operate on can be passed on a single command line.